# What is this format called?

Tags: format

We are switching to this format from an integer.

Does anyone know what is called?

```
c1ddb295-51df-4fca-bc10-8dc1cb8e0d78
18680788-b9ba-4b1a-a93a-81e89830616f
97eb5b39-9963-4d8f-a41e-71adcf7763c6
a51ec154-fcf1-47a3-96bb-33d7d4b20fe0
2567be1e-5f6c-4bb5-8a15-0f37cd67a271
8a978ed7-43a1-4bb9-b341-a4b4aff9a931
154361fa-3972-4d10-b229-b42fa6b2b1f1
047a9367-9837-4c3a-ac3b-3fe98fa40a44
2ab39446-df9b-4310-894f-ecc876278c53
20f40c4f-8344-40ff-973e-e3cd64b002be
74829ff2-5e82-457b-8a20-c007f2dafa18
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier ?

Comment: Thanks, UUID of course

Comment: @RuneStallemo Could you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)
```

Is the name of that `ID` format.

For more information on `UUIDs` you can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier/).

Answer (score 0):

These are 128-bit values that are refered to as UUID (Universally Unique Identifier) a standard identifier.

Ref: [uuidgenerator.net](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/)